# syntax highlighting of multiline php echo statement in notepad++

Tags: php, html, editor, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I'm sure this has been answered before, but i'm tired of searching and don't want to start downloading editors and IDEs without knowing what i'm getting into.

I am just getting started writing php, and i would like to know a way to have notepad++ (or another editor, IDE if necessary) highlight the syntax of a multiline echo statement containing html. I would like to highlight the html inside of the echo.

Comment: Do you want them to highlight HTML inside of the echo?

Comment: I usually just have Notepad++ switch languages, if I have an extra amount of one language or the other.

Comment: I voted to close, because almost every IDE will support this. Which is best is extremely subjective. For me the answer would be vim

Comment: @Evert: What the hell? I mean, I don't even, but, like, what does your close reason have to do with the question?

Comment: @BoltClock I use vim a lot, and I also use Netbeans.  There's absolutely NOTHING wrong with vim, in some ways, it is much more powerful than Netbeans.

Comment: You're asking for other IDE's that will support this; I'm saying almost every IDE will. So you'll need to try try one out and download anyway, despite the fact you don't feel like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Norepad++, NetBeans and other IDEs that I am familiar with there is no way to make the editor highlight html inside echo if your file is recognized by the editor as a PHP file. But you can print html outside of echo statements instead so that html is highlited and use echo only to output php variables inside html. For example:

```
<?php

 $name = 'John';
?>

<b>My name is <?php echo $name;?></b>
```

Comment: so in this example this is a php file?

Comment: yes, this is stored as a php file and both php and html were properly formatted by the IDEs (Notepad++, NetBeans, etc.)

Comment: ok so <??><html>...</html><??> works. can't believe i missed that, thanks!